# Context variable not updating in child component React Context

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have multiple child components (component generate through recursion)  inside my main component. Now the problem is when I updated the context variable in the parent component the child component doesn't render the updated value

here is my context provider

```
 function MainLayoutProvider({ children }) {
  const [mainJson, setMainJson] = useState([
    {
      component:'section',
      id:'1111',
      content:null,
      type:'section',
      cmType:'normal',
      class:'',
      style:{},
      props:{}
    }
  ]);

  return (
    <MainLayout.Provider value={mainJson}>
      <MainDispatchLayout.Provider value={setMainJson}>
        {children}
      </MainDispatchLayout.Provider>
    </MainLayout.Provider>
  );
}
```

Here I included it on my main component

```
function App() {
  return (
    <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
      <MainLayoutProvider>
        <PlayGround></PlayGround>
      </MainLayoutProvider>
    </DndProvider>
  );
}
```

inside the PlayGround component, there is another component name DropSection, where I am updating the 'mainJson' value

```
 function DropSection() {
    const board = useContext(MainLayout);
    const setBoard = useContext(MainDispatchLayout);
    const [{ isOver }, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
    accept: "image",
    drop(item, monitor) {
        const didDrop = monitor.didDrop();
        if (!didDrop ) {
            addItemToBoard(item.sectionName)
        }
    },
    collect: (monitor) => ({
        isOver: !!monitor.isOver(),
    }),
    }));
    const addItemToBoard = (sectionName) => {
        let newJson = {
            component:sectionName,
            id:IdGenerator(),
            content:null,
            type:'text',
            cmType:'normal',
            class:'',
            style:{},
            props:{}
        }
        setBoard((board) => [...board, newJson]);
    };
  
        
    return ( 
        <div  ref={drop}>
        <h4 className="text-center">DropZone</h4>
        {board.map((config,index) => <RenderCard key={config.id} config={config} />)}
        
        </div>
    );
  }
```

but in the RenderCard component, the value of 'mainJson'  is not updating or rendering, I am getting the old value which initializes in MainLayoutContext

```
function RenderCard({config}) {
    const board =useContext(MainLayout);
    const setBoard = useContext(MainDispatchLayout);
      const [{ isOver }, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
        accept: "image",
        drop(item, monitor) {
          const didDrop = monitor.didDrop();
          if (!didDrop ) {
            addItemToBoard(item.sectionName)
          }
          
      },
        collect: (monitor) => ({
          isOver: !!monitor.isOver(),
        }),
      }));

      const addItemToBoard = async (sectionName) => {
        let newJson = {
          component:sectionName,
          id:IdGenerator(),
          content:null,
          type:'text',
          cmType:'normal',
          class:'',
          style:{},
          props:{}
        }
        setBoard((board) => [...board, newJson]);
    };
    if(config.cmType == 'complex'){
      return RenderComplexCard(config)
    }
    var configProperty = {
      style: config.style,
      id:config.id,
    };

    return React.createElement(
      config.component,
      configProperty,
      config.content &&
        ( config.type == "section" && Array.isArray(config.content)  ? config.content.map(c => <RenderCard key={c.id}  config={c} />) : config.content )
    );
```

}

Comment: where is createContext();

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and solved by using `useRef` hook, if you do not want to use `useState`.

Do not forget to reference the variable by using `.current` when accessing it.